# Adding functions to an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

This code adds functions to an array :

```
    var fArr = []
    fArr.push(test())
    fArr.push(test())

    function test(){
        console.log('here')
    }
```

However the function `test()` is invoked each time its added to array `fArr`

Can the function `test()` be added to the array `fArr` without invoking the function ?

I'm attempting to populate the array `fArr` with functions and then iterate over `fArr` and invoke the functions, not invoke the functions as they are being added to `fArr` which is current behavior.

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/3fd83oe1/

Comment: `test()` is executing your function, just do `.push(test)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can add functions to an array.  What you're actually doing is *invoking* the functions and adding the result of the function invocation to the array.  What you want is this:

```
fArr.push(test);
fArr.push(test);
```

Answer (score 2):

It's as simple as:

```
fArr.push(test, test);
```

### Examples

```
var fArr = []

function test() {
    return 'here';
}


fArr(test, test);     
// > Array [ function test(), function test() ]
// Because test evaluates to itself

fArr(test(), test());
// > Array [ "here", "here" ]
// Because test() evaluates to 'here'
```

Comment: +1 for reminding us that `Array.prototype.push` takes multiple arguments.