# Add Functions with params to Array Javascript (Node.js)

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I want to push functions with params to an array without getting them executed. Here is what i have tried so far:

```
 var load_helpers = require('../helpers/agentHelper/loadFunctions.js');
 var load_functions = [];
 load_functions.push(load_helpers.loadAgentListings(callback , agent_ids));
 load_functions.push(load_helpers.loadAgentCount(callback , agent_data));
```

But in this way functions gets executed while pushing. [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27023870/adding-functions-to-an-array) provides similar example but without params. How can I include params in this example?

Comment: Are you bound to the array structure? Else I'd suggest a solution with an object containing references to the function and the arguments.

Comment: Yes I need to pass this array to `async.parallel([] , callback());` There might be a workaround with object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Push functions which do what you want:

```
load_functions.push(
  () => load_helpers.loadAgentListings(callback, agent_ids),      
  () => load_helpers.loadAgentCount   (callback, agent_data)
);
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to **bind** the parameters to the function.
The first parameter is the 'thisArg'.

```
function MyFunction(param1, param2){
   console.log('Param1:', param1, 'Param2:', param2)
}

var load_functions = [];
load_functions.push(MyFunction.bind(undefined, 1, 2));
load_functions[0](); // Param1: 1 Param2: 2
```

Comment: No, you don't **have to** bind the parameters, although that's one approach. It's more readable and idiomatic with arrow functions to write `() => Myfunction(1, 2)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap added elements with function like that, let's mock `load_helpers`

```
var load_helpers = {
  loadAgentListings: function(fn, args) {
    args.forEach(fn)
  }
}
```

And try to use it in that way:

```
var a = []

a.push(function() {
  return load_helpers.loadAgentListings(function(r) {
    console.log(r)
  }, ['a', 'b', 'c'])
})

a[0]() // just execution
```

All depends on what level you want to pass additional arguments, second proof of concept

```
var a = []

a.push(function(args) {
  return load_helpers.loadAgentListings(function(r) {
    console.log(r)
  }, args)
})

a[0](['a', 'b', 'c']) // execution with arguments
```

With the bindings:

```
var a = []

a.push(load_helpers.loadAgentListings.bind(null, (function(r) {return r * 2})))

console.log(a[0]([1, 2, 3])) // execution with additional parameters
```